# Calculate/Mutate every N Column

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate my data for every N rows (e.g. every 4 rows).

**data**

```
A <- c(1,4,5,7,8,10,3)
B <- c(2,4,1,8,9,2,5)
df <- data.frame(A,B)
```

What I want to do is averaging the data from A and B (every 4 rows) and divide both value.
This is the output that I want.

```
A   B   Calc
1   2   1.133333333
4   4   1.090909091
5   1   1.5
7   8   1.166666667
8   9   1.3125
10  2   1.857142857
3   5   0.6
```

I can do the calculation easily in excel by doing this `=(AVERAGE(A2:A5))/(AVERAGE(B2:B5))` for the first row. The next row `=(AVERAGE(A3:A6))/(AVERAGE(B3:B6))`, and last row `=(AVERAGE(A8:A11))/(AVERAGE(B8:B11))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zoo`'s `rollapply` function to do this rolling calculation.

```
library(zoo)

transform(df, Calc = rollapply(A, 4, align = 'left', mean, partial = TRUE)/
                     rollapply(B, 4, align = 'left', mean, partial = TRUE))

#   A B     Calc
#1  1 2 1.133333
#2  4 4 1.090909
#3  5 1 1.500000
#4  7 8 1.166667
#5  8 9 1.312500
#6 10 2 1.857143
#7  3 5 0.600000
```

PS - There is also `rollmean` function but it doesn't have `partial = TRUE` argument which makes the output unbalanced to fit as a new column in `df`.